# Junit - ExceptionInInitializerError caused by org.hibernate.AnnotationException

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I am getting this error when I try to run Junit for my class:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.dao.dashboard.TestDashboardDAO.setUp(TestDashboardDAO.java:36)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: xxx.yyy.zzz.bis.dashboard.details.dataDetails[xxx.yyy.zzz.bis.details.DataDetails]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1393)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.dao.helper.TestSchema.<init>(TestSchema.java:62)
    ... 14 more
```

```
@OneToMany()
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name="ID",referencedColumnName = "ID",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private List<DataDetails> dataDetails;
```

Inside the setUp method, I just called initializer method. Which was not invoked.
What should I do to run the test successfully?

Comment: Can you post the DataDetails.java? Might not be part of db model

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pojo mapping in your cfg xml file.

```
<mapping class="xxx.yyy.zzz.bis.details.DataDetails" />
```

and make sure you specify appropriate qualified name of DataDetails in mapping. because your exception shows two different qualified names.